# Need help getting and setting call state in Avaya one-X Agent

Tags: avaya

The PCs in my area at work have Avaya one-X Agent 2.5.7.6.

I am writing a program to automate some commonly used call functions. I have the Avaya one-X Agent 2.5 API guide and using it,I have managed to interface to one-X and perform some of the functions I need (dialing numbers, answering/releasing calls, putting them on hold).

Nevertheless, there are some additional things I need to do that the guide doesn't mention.  Specifically, I need to be able to :

- query and set the work state (auto-in/ready, ACW, and some of the aux modes)
- transferring the current call to one of several commonly dialed numbers.

Can you point to me to any documentation or links where I can find information about these operations?

Answer (score 1):

one-X Agent HTTP API does not support these methods.

This functionality can be implemented using AVAYA AES server-side API.
You could use [DMCC](http://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/dmcc/overview/index.gsp) (which has bindings to different languages and also a language-agnostic XML interface), which implements CSTA ECMA-269 industrial standard.

Specifically, you'll need Get/Set Agent State methods to control work state and Single Step Transfer Call method to redirect a call. You'll need DMCC 6.x version for Agent State functionality.